# Suggesting similar commands on Arch Linux

Tags: command-line, arch-linux

One thing I like about using Ubuntu is that it suggests similar commands (and packages with similar commands) when a non-existent command is entered.

I'm on Manjaro, and when I mistype a command, say `msg` instead of `mesg`, it only returns `bash: msg: command not found`. I'd like to have a `Did you mean [similar command]` message like on Ubuntu.

Is there a way to get such suggestions for similar commands on Arch Linux?

Answer (score 4):

You could install `pacman -S pkgfile`, do `sudo pkgfile --update` and add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
source /usr/share/doc/pkgfile/command-not-found.bash
```

from the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash#Command_not_found):

> Then attempting to run an unavailable command will show the following info:
>
> $ abiword
>
> abiword may be found in the following packages:
> extra/abiword 3.0.1-2    /usr/bin/abiword

This will not search for similar commands though.

There is also the AUR [command-not-found package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/command-not-found) that promises more but is currently flagged as out of date. You may be able to contact the author on github (https://github.com/metti/command-not-found).

Comment: The AUR package has been flagged out-of-date since the past 1 year.

Comment: @AmitSingh thanks, I missed that

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not find any packages that are available right now that implement this for Arch Linux, I tried to hack together a solution for the same.

For this solution, we take advantage of the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable and `compgen`.

**Steps**

1. Create a python file with the following content. I'm naming it as `temp.py`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

def similar_words(word):
    """
    return a set with spelling1 distance alternative spellings

    based on http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html
    """
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-_0123456789'
    s = [(word[:i], word[i:]) for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
    deletes = [a + b[1:] for a, b in s if b]
    transposes = [a + b[1] + b[0] + b[2:] for a, b in s if len(b) > 1]
    replaces = [a + c + b[1:] for a, b in s for c in alphabet if b]
    inserts = [a + c + b     for a, b in s for c in alphabet]
    return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)

def bash_command(cmd):
    import subprocess
    sp = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return [s.decode('utf-8').strip() for s in sp.stdout.readlines()]

def main():
    word = sys.argv[1]
    command_list = bash_command('compgen -ck')
    result = list(set(similar_words(word)).intersection(set(command_list)))

    if len(result) > 0:
        wrong_command_str = "Did you mean?"
        indent = len(wrong_command_str)//2

        print("Did you mean?")
        for cmd in result:
            print(indent*" ",cmd)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

2. Append the python script to your `$PROMPT_COMMAND` variable.

```bsh
export PROMPT_COMMAND='if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then python test.py $(fc -nl | tail -n 1 | awk "{print $1}"); fi;'$PROMPT_COMMAND
```

1. Check if previous command has failed. `$? -gt 0`
2. If failed, get the name of the command. `fc -nl | tail -n 1 | awk "{print $1}"`
3. Find close matches using the python script. `python test.py <command-name>`

[image: Working sample screenshot]